# The .push-function does only work on an array in this nested object but not a normal string?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to add a **.push(value)** to an object. More will be explained after the code.

Here is the entire code:

```
var collection = {
"1": {
    "artist": "Travis Scott",
    "album": "ASTROWORLD",
    "tracks": [
        "STARGAZING"
    ]
},
"2": {
    "album": "Barter 6",
    "tracks": [
        "With That",
        "Check"
    ]
},
"3": {
    "artist": "XXXTENTACION",
    "tracks": [
        "Moonlight",
        "Jocelyn Flores"
    ]
}
};

function editCollection(id, prop, val) {
if (val === "") {
    delete collection[id][prop];
} else if (prop === "tracks") {
    collection[id][prop] = collection[id][prop] || [];
    collection[id][prop].push(val);
} else if (prop === "artist") {
    collection[id][prop].push(val);
}
    else {
    collection[id][prop] = val;
}
return collection;
}

editCollection(1, "tracks", ["CAROUSEL", "SICKO MODE"]);
console.log(editCollection(3, "artist", " and Ski Mask"));
```

Why can I **.push** values to the "tracks"-property but not to the "artist"-property? Can some one explain?

Comment: Because the `artist` property value is not an array

Comment: Because push method exists only on arrays and thats why it is works on tracks and not on artist.

Comment: Oh so .push only works with arrays? What can you use with strings? @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest 1 of two options:

1. make `artist` an array and continue to use push (for most use cases, I'd think this was the better option. Example:

```
"1": {
   "artist": ["Travis Scott"],
   "album": "ASTROWORLD",
   "tracks": [
       "STARGAZING"
   ]
},
```

2. Use string concatenation - [see MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Concatenating_strings). example:

```
else if (prop === "artist") {
   collection[id][prop] = collection[id][prop] + " " + val;
}
```